# android constraintLayout - How to use horizontal barrier to move upwards?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am in need a of a [horizontal barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier) between a view and a textview.  essentially what i want to happen is if the text grows horizontally then it should push the barrier upwards.  here is what i have so far :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="12dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_voucher_code_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="24dp" />


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="405dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:background="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/close_white_x" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/fui_medium_extd"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:letterSpacing="0.07"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="NICE TO MEET YOU!" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.02"
            android:shadowColor="#16000000"
            android:shadowDy="2"
            android:shadowRadius="9"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_end"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_start"
            tools:text="Enjoy 20% off your first purchase on the App." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_code"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/fui_medium_extd"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:letterSpacing="0.04"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/btn_apply"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_voucher_code_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv"
            tools:text="APPY20" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_voucher_code_start"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_apply"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_apply" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_apply"
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:background="@color/action_blue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/fui_medium_extd"
            android:text="@string/APPLY"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_category_cta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/regular_extd"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SHOP NOW >"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tv_category_cta"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/tv_category_cta"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_category_cta" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:background="#979797"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line2"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:barrierDirection="top"

            app:constraint_referenced_ids="line3"
             />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_terms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
            android:text="T&amp;C
Voucher code blah blah this text should push upwards, but its not, why ?
\n\n\n\n\n
adf
adf
dsa
fdafs\n
das\n
fda\n
sfadfs
adsf
asdf
asdf
asdf
asfd
asdf
asdf
asdf
asdf
\n\n\n\n
"
            android:textColor="#696969"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_start"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line3" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Look at the barrier code i have, its suppose to go upwards as i have direction set to "top".  but when i add a bunch of text its not pushing upwards. why ? Essentially there is a view called line3 i want that view to push upwards when the textview grows horizontally. so i put the barrier betweeen line3 and the textview. what have i missed ?

Comment: it won't go top because you have fixed it to stay there.  This line `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line2"` will make sure it stays there you will have to remove it. :)

Comment: if i remove it then it wont have a vertical constraint. how to make it not move to top if i delete that constraint

Comment: For that you need to use relativeLayout. Adding the constraint will fix it the specific place. And another suggestion is you can also add scroll to your textview if you want to show all the text ?

Answer (score -1):

You remember add:

```
app:barrierDirection="start"
app:constraint_referenced_ids="viewId,textId"
```

Comment: those are already there. why should i use "start" i want it to move upwards